# How this C program is work?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
long x;
float t;
scanf("%f",&t);
printf("%d\n",t);
x=90;
printf("%f\n",x);
{
    x=1;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    {
        x=30;
        printf("%f\n",x);
    }
    printf("%f\n",x);
}
    x==9;
    printf("%f\n",x);
}
```

For I/P 7 it print 0 and six times 7.
How this code is working?
i know that behavior is undefined if we print variable with other than corresponding format specifier , but why this print 6 everytime ?

Comment: Because anything can happen when the behaviour is undefined. It might even write a doctorate thesis on your screen if you run it ≈ ∞ times.

Comment: There's no such question as "why?" when it comes to undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think the answer is any deeper than: because on your version of your compiler, with your current build settings, `printf` happens to think it has received a `6`. It likely wouldn't on different build settings, might not on a different version and almost certainly wouldn't on my computer. (EDIT: actually, it definitely wouldn't because my C compiler is modern enough to require an `int` return type on `main`)

Comment: @AnT sure there is. you just need to specify your exact c implementation, and then "why?" is a fine question

Comment: @Steve Cox: Not really. "Specifying the exact C implementation" is not even remotely sufficient. For this specific case, you would also need the exact configuration settings of the compiler. In general case, you'd need the current date, the inside and outside temperature, the current weather condition and infinitude of other parameters, which is exactly why the "why?" question is meaningless.

Comment: @AnT "exact configuration settings of the compiler" that is part of the C implementation according to the language of the standard. "you'd need the current date, the inside and outside temperature &c". I get that you're just being hyperbolic, but seriously C implementations are going to be consistent even with runtime UB. "why?" is an examination of the implementation, not the language itself.

Comment: Here's an idea - why don't you disassemble it., run it through a debugger and tell us why it does what it does in your particular environment?

Answer (score 3):

"Undefined behavior" is just that -- undefined.  The fact that it's undefined makes "why is it doing that?" an invalid question.

Answer (score 0):

Without proper format specifiers its obvious that the output will be erratic. As to "why" this happens rests on the compiler to decide.